# Why can I call Write::write_all on a shared reference even though it requires a mutable reference?

Tags: rust

I'm playing with a function that handles a TCP connection:

```
use std::{io::Write, net::TcpStream, sync::Arc};

fn handle_connection(stream: TcpStream) {
    let data = "Hello!\n";

    let stream_arc = Arc::new(stream);
    let mut s: &TcpStream = &*stream_arc; //let mut s = Deref::deref(&stream_arc);

    s.write_all(data.as_bytes()).unwrap(); //same as Write::write_all(&mut s, data.as_bytes()).unwrap();
}
```

I can't figure out why Rust doesn't complain about `Write::write_all` since `s` is not a mutable reference. I noticed also that removing `mut` from `s` compilation fails. Am I missing some trait implementation that permits this? Is this a way to mutably borrow from `std::sync::Arc`?

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: Calling a method will automatically take a (mutable) borrow of a variable. `Write` is implemented for [immutable references to `TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-Write-1). You have a `&mut &TcpStream`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Oh, thanks, i missed that implementation.

Comment: You'll note that one of the duplicates is my own question, so I was once in the same position as you!